# add a variable and ternary expression as class in ng-class?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have scope variable

```
$scope.blur = 'blur';
```

and I have an element as :

```
<ion-content class="business-search-result" ng-class="showIcons ? 'category-page' : ''" on-tap="hideFloatingActions()">
```

Now how can i add my variable `$scope.blur` to `ng-class` so that ng-class will have two classes.....one from the expression and one from my variable?

I want :

```
<ion-content class="business-search-result" ng-class="blur showIcons ? 'category-page' : ''" on-tap="hideFloatingActions()">
```

but this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-class="[blur].concat(showIcons ? ['category-page'] : [])"
```

should do the trick. But maybe you should have that logic in the controller, and not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
ng-class="{blur: true, 'category-page': showIcons}"
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but it would add the class 'blur', always, and not the value of the scope variable `blur` as a class.